# Multi Thread server

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am writing multi thread server but i have problem in accept connection and start read function. i don't know where i should write them..
here is my code:
"mythread.cpp"

```
#include "mythread.h"
#include "myserver.h"

mythread::mythread(qintptr ID, QObject *parent) :
QThread(parent)
{
this->socketDescriptor = ID;
}


void mythread::run()
 {

  qDebug() << " Thread started";
 }


void mythread::acceptConnection()
 {

  c_client = s_server.nextPendingConnection();

  connect(c_client,SIGNAL(readyRead()),

   this, SLOT(startRead()));
   }

 void mythread::startRead()
 {

 char buffer[1024] = {0};

 c_client->read(buffer, c_client->bytesAvailable());

 qDebug() << buffer;

 }

 void mythread::readyRead()
 {
QByteArray Data = socket->readAll();

qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Data in: " << Data;

socket->write(Data);
}

void mythread::disconnected()
 {
qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Disconnected";


socket->deleteLater();
exit(0);
 }
```

"myserver.cpp"

```
#include "myserver.h"
#include "mythread.h"


myserver::myserver(QObject *parent) :

QObject(parent)
{
}

void myserver::startserver()
{
int port = 1234;
if(s_server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, port))
{
    qDebug() << "Could not start server";
}
else
{
    qDebug() << "Listening to port " << port ;
  }

  }
   void myserver::incomingconnection(int socketDescriptor)
  {
  connect(&s_server, SIGNAL(newConnection()),
  this, SLOT(acceptConnection()));

s_server.listen(QHostAddress::Any, 1234);

qDebug() << socketDescriptor << " Connecting...";

mythread *thread = new mythread(socketDescriptor,this);

connect(thread, SIGNAL(finished()), thread, SLOT(deleteLater()));

thread->start();

 }
```

i would be grateful if you help me.

Comment: does your code work for one connection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using QThread very well. you can use SIGNAL and SLOTS ,and MoveToThread() function. google it.

when you use QThread, the code in Run() function will be run in another thread. acceptConnection will run in main thread.

also search for nextPendingConnection();

```
void myserver::incomingconnection(int socketDescriptor)
{
connect(&s_server, SIGNAL(newConnection()),this, SLOT(acceptConnection()));
...
```

is not OK. this connect should be called once (maybe constructor). not for any incomming connection.

Comment: `nextPendingConnection` should be called on each incoming connection, not only once: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtcpserver.html#nextPendingConnection

Comment: Talking about ways of how to use `QThread` is not related to a question. It is OK to override `run` method, if you understand what you do. Usage of `moveToThread` + some worker class or usage of inherited `QThread` - is on your choise, please, don't impose your opinion (you are not first, who did it ;). But I agree, that @Hanita do it wrong.